# View Not Found laravel , Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

problem in heroku paths :

> in FileViewFinder.php line 137
>       at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('page.test', array('/tmp/build_3ca8cb630d32dd0becc5ffb91cd9279d/resources/views'))

when i try

```
return 'Hello World!';
```

worked without any problem

Comment: Try `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @namelivia the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded your laravel version? if not please make if view file exists after running `php artisan cache:clear` & `php artisan view:clear`